# Slow processing of a python dataframe when aggregating across rows and columns

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

Discovered a new resource, and this question has been posted to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/278083/slow-processing-of-a-python-dataframe-when-aggregating-across-rows-and-columns

I have a dataframe of shape [20225 rows x 7 columns], and there a bit of transformation required. There are sometimes duplicate rows, but only in one column. So what I want to do is find the duplicate rows (where the name is the same) and then

1. Concatenate all the email addresses in three columns and name matching rows into one string (dropping nulls)
2. Concatenate all the company names in three columns and name matching rows into one string (dropping nulls)
3. Create a new dataframe of shape [20106 rows x 3 columns] that then has one row per name, with a single string of email addresses in the second column, and a single string of companies in the third column.

Basically, the duplicate rows have been eliminated, and the different email addresses/companynames have been concatenated.

My code works, and takes about 6 minutes to run... I don't know enough about this, but I have a hunch it could be a lot faster. I'm just looking for some pointers as to maybe structuring it differently? Thanks for any guidance.

*EXAMPLE DATA*

| Name | People1.Email | People1.CompanyName | People2.Email | People2.CompanyName | People3.Email | People3.CompanyName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person A | email@somewhere.com | CompanyName | email@somewhere.com | CompanyName |  |  |
| Person A | email@somewhere.com | CompanyName | email@somewhere.com | CompanyName |  |  |
| Person B |  |  | email@somewhere.com | CompanyName | email@somewhere.com | CompanyName |
| Person C | email@somewhere.com | CompanyName | email@somewhere.com | CompanyName | email@somewhere.com CompanyName |  |
| Person D | email@somewhere.com | CompanyName |  |  |  |  |
| Person D |  |  | email@somewhere.com | CompanyName |  |  |
| Person D | email@somewhere.com | CompanyName | email@somewhere.com | CompanyName |  |  |
| Person E | email@somewhere.com | CompanyName | email@somewhere.com | CompanyName | email@somewhere.com | CompanyName |
| Person E | email@somewhere.com | CompanyName | email@somewhere.com | CompanyName | email@somewhere.com | CompanyName |

| Name | Emails | Companies |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person A | email@somewhere.com;email@somewhere.com;email@somewhere.com;email@somewhere.com | CompanyName; CompanyName;CompanyName; CompanyName |
| Person B | email@somewhere.com;email@somewhere.com | CompanyName; CompanyName;CompanyName |
| etc |  |  |

```
*DATA TYPES*

Name                               object
People1.Email                      object
People2.CompanyName                object
People1.Email                      object
People2.CompanyName                object
People3.Email                      object
People4.CompanyName                object


*CODE*

print (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime()) + " start")
pd_xl_file = pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\sample.xlsx')
df = pd_xl_file.parse(0)

listOfPeople = df['Name'].unique().tolist()

# Now creata new df to hold the final result 
df_new = pd.DataFrame()

for person in listOfPeople:
    lstCompanies = 
    df.loc[df['Name'] == person, 'People1.CompanyName'].unique().tolist()  + 
    df.loc[df['Name'] == person, 'People2.CompanyName'].unique().tolist()  +
    df.loc[df['Name'] == person, 'People3.CompanyName'].unique().tolist()

    Companies = [x for x in lstCompanies if pd.isnull(x) == False]

    lstEmails = 
    df.loc[df['Name'] == person, 'People1.Email'].unique().tolist()  + 
    df.loc[df['Name'] == person, 'People2.Email'].unique().tolist() +
    df.loc[df['Name'] == person, 'People3.Email'].unique().tolist()

    Emails = [x for x in lstEmails if pd.isnull(x) == False]

    # initialize list of lists
    c = ' '.join([item for item in Companies])
    e = ' '.join([item for item in Emails])

  
    # append to the final result
    new_row = pd.DataFrame({'Name':person, 'Companies':c, 'Emails':e}, index=[0])
    df_new = pd.concat([new_row,df_new.loc[:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
    print ('.', end='')

print (df_new)
print (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime()) + " end")
```

Comment: Questions related to improving the efficiency and/or run time of working code are more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: I did not know that existed, thanks for the pointer.